# Best initial state for maximum information

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I was reading a [paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.95.032129) ([pdf](https://www.quantumbiology.gr/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/PRA_2017.pdf)) and eq.(4) states that the maximum Fisher information is obtained for the initial state
$$\vert{\psi}\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\vert{\lambda_{\max}}\rangle+\vert{\lambda_{\min}}\rangle)$$
where $\vert{\lambda_{\max}}\rangle$ and $\vert{\lambda_{\min}}\rangle$ are the eigenvectors of the generator given by eq.(3) from the paper. I tried using these relations for the simple system of a single electron with a spin-up initial state in a magnetic field in the x,y direction. I have found that
$$\begin{equation}
    \hat{\text{H}}=\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & -\frac{\text{B}}{2}e^{-i\varphi}\\
    -\frac{\text{B}}{2}e^{i\varphi} & 0
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}$$
$$\begin{equation}
    \vert{+\frac{\text{B}}{2}}\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
    1\\
    -e^{i\varphi}
    \end{pmatrix} \ \ , \ \
    \vert{-\frac{\text{B}}{2}}\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
    1\\
    e^{i\varphi}
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}$$
The generator for the angle $\varphi$ is
$$\begin{equation}
    h_\varphi=\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & -ie^{-iBt/2}\sin(\frac{\text{Bt}}{2})\\
    ie^{iBt/2}\sin({\frac{\text{Bt}}{2}}) & 0
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}$$
and thus, assuming that $e^{i\theta}$ is an arbitrary phase, i found that the initial state that maximizes Fisher information is
$$\begin{equation}
    \vert{\psi}\rangle=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
    1+e^{i\theta}\\
    ie^{iBt/2}(1-e^{i\theta})
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}$$
The problem that I have with this initial state is that the term $e^{iBt/2}$ has time explicitly. Shouldn't I get an initial state that does not include time? Also, is it correct if I take $t=0$?